# PHP Include multiple files are trying to merge SQL Queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webpage that automatically refreshes every 20 seconds to check for new emails and a few other bits.

The one file automate.php has `<?php include ... ?>` for about 6 files.

In all 6 of the files that are included they run SQL Queries but if two run at one through the automate.php file sometimes they try to go together.

for example, if `include1.php` and `include2.php` both run a query at the same time

```
include1.php:
($sql="QUERY HERE";)

include2.php:
($sql="QUERY HERE";)
```

they are both `$sql` so they dont know the differece.

Whats the best way to stop this from happening?

Comment: you should distroy the sql variable in each includ file; `unset($sql);`... ort try Object-oriented style

Answer (score 0):

it's not a problem that they run simultaneously (which I'm not sure they do in this case).

If you have a website that has a form that inputs some information into a database each time it's filled out, if two people fill out the form at exactly the same time does this break the website?

EDIT: if I've misunderstood this and you actually meant that query 2 is using the query stored in the first $sql , it doesn't because you've redefined it for the second query, and re defined it again for query 3 / 4 / 5 etc. IE:

```
//query 1
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `test`'; 
//rest of query 

//query 2    
$sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM `test2`;
```

//$sql no longer = 'SELECT * FROM `test`' as you've just redefined it as 'SELECT count(*) FROM `test2`;

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I'd do it:

1. Turn your includes into classes (Models)

   ```
   class Model1 {
       function getBlah($param) {
           // Do sql here.
       }

       // other functions here.
   }
   ```
2. Then call an SQL method from each class in the order you want.

   ```
   $obj = new Model1();
   echo $obj->getBlah('Horse');
   ```